# Spark job returns a different result on each run

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am working on a scala code which performs Linear Regression on certain datasets. Right now I am using 20 cores and 25 executors and everytime I run a Spark job I get a different result.

The input size of the files are 2GB and 400 MB.However, when I run the job with 20 cores and 1 executor, I get consistent results.

Has anyone experienced such a thing so far?

Please find the code below:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD
import org.apache.spark.Partitioner
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel

object TextProcess{
  def main(args: Array[String]){
            val conf = new SparkConf().set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
            val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
            val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
            val numExecutors=(conf.get("spark.executor.instances").toInt)
            // Read the 2 input files
            // First file is either cases / controls
            val input1 = sc.textFile(args(0))
            // Second file is Gene Expression
            val input2 = sc.textFile(args(1))

              //collecting header information
            val header1=sc.parallelize(input1.take(1))
            val header2=sc.parallelize(input2.take(1))

            //mapping data without the header information
            val map1 = input1.subtract(header1).map(x => (x.split(" ")(0)+x.split(" ")(1), x))
            val map2 = input2.subtract(header2).map(x => (x.split(" ")(0)+x.split(" ")(1), x))


            //joining data. here is where the order was getting affected. 
            val joinedMap = map1.join(map2)

            //adding the header back to the top of RDD
            val x = header1.union(joinedMap.map{case(x,(y,z))=>y})

            val y = header2.union(joinedMap.map{case(x,(y,z))=>z})

            //removing irrelevant columns
            val rddX = x.map(x=>x.split(" ").drop(3)).zipWithIndex.map{case(a,b)=> a.map(x=>b.toString+" "+x.toString)}
            val rddY = y.map(x=>x.split(" ").drop(2)).zipWithIndex.map{case(a,b)=> a.map(x=>b.toString+" "+x.toString)}


            //transposing and cross joining data. This keeps the identifier at the start
            val transposedX = rddX.flatMap(x => x.zipWithIndex.map(x=>x.swap)).reduceByKey((a,b)=> a+":"+b).map{case(a,b)=>b.split(":").sorted}
            val transposedY = rddY.flatMap(x => x.zipWithIndex.map(x=>x.swap)).reduceByKey((a,b)=> a+":"+b).map{case(a,b)=>b.split(":").sorted}.persist(StorageLevel.apply(false, true, false, false, numExecutors))

            val cleanedX = transposedX.map(x=>x.map(x=>x.slice(x.indexOfSlice(" ")+1,x.length)))
            val cleanedY = transposedY.map(x=>x.map(x=>x.slice(x.indexOfSlice(" ")+1,x.length))).persist(StorageLevel.apply(false, true, false, false, numExecutors))


            val cartXY = cleanedX.cartesian(cleanedY)
            val finalDataSet= cartXY.map{case(a,b)=>a zip b} 
            //convert to key value pair
            val regressiondataset = finalDataSet.map(x=>(x(0),x.drop(1).filter{case(a,b)=> a!="NA" && b!="NA" && a!="null" && b!="null"}.map{case(a,b)=> (a.toDouble, b.toDouble)}))


            val linearOutput = regressiondataset.map(s => new LinearRegression(s._1 ,s._2).outputVal)

            linearOutput.saveAsTextFile(args(2))
            cleanedY.unpersist()
            transposedY.unpersist()

  }
}


class LinearRegression (val keys: (String, String),val pairs: Array[(Double,Double)]) {


  val size = pairs.size

  // first pass: read in data, compute xbar and ybar
  val sums = pairs.aggregate(new X_X2_Y(0D,0D,0D))(_ + new X_X2_Y(_),_+_)
  val bars = (sums.x / size, sums.y / size)

  // second pass: compute summary statistics
  val sumstats = pairs.foldLeft(new X2_Y2_XY(0D,0D,0D))(_ + new X2_Y2_XY(_, bars))

  val beta1 = sumstats.xy / sumstats.x2
  val beta0 = bars._2 - (beta1 * bars._1)
  val betas = (beta0, beta1)

  //println("y = " + ("%4.3f" format beta1) + " * x + " + ("%4.3f" format beta0))


  // analyze results
  val correlation = pairs.aggregate(new RSS_SSR(0D,0D))(_ + RSS_SSR.build(_, bars, betas),_+_)
  val R2 = correlation.ssr / sumstats.y2
  val svar = correlation.rss / (size - 2)
  val svar1 = svar / sumstats.x2
  val svar0 = ( svar / size ) + ( bars._1 * bars._1 * svar1)
  val svar0bis = svar * sums.x2 / (size * sumstats.x2)

  /* println("R^2                 = " + R2)
   println("std error of beta_1 = " + Math.sqrt(svar1))
   println("std error of beta_0 = " + Math.sqrt(svar0))
   println("std error of beta_0 = " + Math.sqrt(svar0bis))
   println("SSTO = " + sumstats.y2)
   println("SSE  = " + correlation.rss)
   println("SSR  = " + correlation.ssr)*/


  def outputVal() = keys._1
                    +"\t"+keys._2
                    +"\t"+beta1
                    +"\t"+beta0
                    +"\t"+R2
                    +"\t"+Math.sqrt(svar1)
                    +"\t"+Math.sqrt(svar0)
                    +"\t"+sumstats.y2
                    +"\t"+correlation.rss
                    +"\t"+correlation.ssr+"\t;

}


object RSS_SSR {
  def build(p: (Double,Double), bars: (Double,Double), betas: (Double,Double)): RSS_SSR = {
    val fit = (betas._2 * p._1) + betas._1
    val rss = (fit-p._2) * (fit-p._2)
    val ssr = (fit-bars._2) * (fit-bars._2)
    new RSS_SSR(rss, ssr)
  }
}

class RSS_SSR(val rss: Double, val ssr: Double) {
  def +(p: RSS_SSR): RSS_SSR = new RSS_SSR(rss+p.rss, ssr+p.ssr)
}

class X_X2_Y(val x: Double, val x2: Double, val y: Double) {
  def this(p: (Double,Double)) = this(p._1, p._1*p._1, p._2)
  def +(p: X_X2_Y): X_X2_Y = new X_X2_Y(x+p.x,x2+p.x2,y+p.y)
}

class X2_Y2_XY(val x2: Double, val y2: Double, val xy: Double) {
  def this(p: (Double,Double), bars: (Double,Double)) = this((p._1-bars._1)*(p._1-bars._1), (p._2-bars._2)*(p._2-bars._2),(p._1-bars._1)*(p._2-bars._2))
  def +(p: X2_Y2_XY): X2_Y2_XY = new X2_Y2_XY(x2+p.x2,y2+p.y2,xy+p.xy)
}
```

Comment: Just a wild guess, `.union` as I understand may not preserve ordering, so your header may end up you never know where. Will it change your result?

Comment: Victor thank you for the reply. Is there an alternative to union?.

Comment: What do you mean "different result"? @VictorMoroz is right, Spark in general, being parallel AND distributed, is not focused to getting outputs in the same order (each record on an RDD to be processed can move around). But the set of results should be the same.

Comment: It is not about the order here. I have about 2 columns as the key and 4 other columns as the values. So everytime I run a job, for the same key  I get different values. I hope this helps?

Comment: I think this question has been asked before. Anyway please provide the definition of LinearRegression.

Comment: Yes Paul, I have asked this question before. I added the LinearRegression code.

Comment: I faced a similar issue but in in different context. Problem was: ties were resolved differently while sorting during each execution. In your code while transposing there is some kind of sorting involved. Can you make sure either there are no ties, or if there are ties, they are being resolved in same manner. I achieved that by using many variable in sorting (so there were no ties anymore).